# Saving covariance matrix in a for loop - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, covariance

So there is a hobby project I am currently working on in order to improve my R skills. What I created with my previous code are various subsets of data "returnseries.1, returnseries.2, returnseries.3, ... "(from 1 to 119) which are stored each in a 252x6 matrix.

Now I am building a for loop to calculate the covariance matrix for each subset.

My code goes as the following:

```
for(k in 1:119){
covmat[k] = matrix(c(cov(returnseries[k])),nrow=6, ncol=6)
}
```

For some reason I get the error that: `"My column index must be at most 7 not 8."`

And I don't get why. I tried several other code versions but nothing gives me an answer. Thought that it had to do with the naming but using `return series.[k]` is providing me an error, that returnseries. is not defined

Would be delighted if somebody could provide a quick

Comment: you want to store 119 6x6 matrices? you'll want to store them in a 6x6x119 array

Comment: Hi there Michael. Exactly I want to store 119 6x6 matrices

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array. A 3D array in this case.

Generate some data.

```
> xy <- list(one = matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3),
+            two = matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3),
+            three = matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3))
> xy
$one
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.1341714 -1.27229790  0.22431441
[2,]  1.0853899  0.02335881 -0.05600098
[3,] -1.5645181  0.83745858 -1.47670091

$two
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  1.4891642 -0.3766222 -0.86981432
[2,]  0.3424295 -1.7882177  1.79601480
[3,] -1.1583058 -0.1604330  0.02690498

$three
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.1511346 -0.3672432 -0.3008405
[2,] -1.9881830 -0.8545396 -0.7108430
[3,]  0.1637134 -0.7958267  1.1923535
```

Create empty array

```
> N <- 3
> ar <- array(rep(NA, 3*3*N), dim = c(3, 3, N))
> ar
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Fill in values.

```
> for (i in 1:N) {
+   ar[,, i] <- xy[[i]]
+ }
> 
> ar
, , 1

           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.1341714 -1.27229790  0.22431441
[2,]  1.0853899  0.02335881 -0.05600098
[3,] -1.5645181  0.83745858 -1.47670091

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  1.4891642 -0.3766222 -0.86981432
[2,]  0.3424295 -1.7882177  1.79601480
[3,] -1.1583058 -0.1604330  0.02690498

, , 3

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.1511346 -0.3672432 -0.3008405
[2,] -1.9881830 -0.8545396 -0.7108430
[3,]  0.1637134 -0.7958267  1.1923535
```

You can do all sorts of wonderful things with this now. For example, do row sums.

```
> apply(ar, MARGIN = 3, FUN = rowSums)
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.9138121  0.2427277 -0.8192183
[2,]  1.0527477  0.3502266 -3.5535656
[3,] -2.2037604 -1.2918338  0.5602402
```

Here's proof for the first matrix. Compare it to the first column:

```
> rowSums(xy[[1]])
[1] -0.9138121  1.0527477 -2.2037604
```

Comment: Hi Roman thanks for your quick reply but unfortunately this one isn't working out

Comment: @ArthurVott this is just an example. You will have to adapt your code a bit. Also, can you be more specific as to what is not working?